# Estimate, I couldn't prove.

Tags: real-analysis

I have the suggestion that the following estimate is true for all $k\geq 2$:

$$\frac{4}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k-1}\left(\frac{4}{n}+1\right)^i\leq \left(\frac{4}{n}+1\right)^{k+1}+(k+1)$$

I tryed a lot, but couldn't solve it yet. Do you have an idea? If it helps, i can post my approaches.

Thank you!

Comment: You might want to come up with a better title.

Comment: @Asaf: This one looks invitingly like the first line of a poem, though.

Comment: Isn't this easily solveable using the geometric series? We know that for all $k \ge 1$, $\sum_{i=1}^k q^k = \frac{q^{k+1}-1}{q-1}$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac{4}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k-1}\left(\frac{4}{n}+1\right)^i = \left(1+\frac{4}{n}\right)^k-\left(1+\frac{4}{n}\right) \leq \left(\frac{4}{n}+1\right)^{k+1}$

the left hand of the inequality is a geometrical series.

Comment: To be more precise, let $q := \frac{4}{n} - 1$. Then $$\frac{4}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{k-1} \left(\frac{4}{n}+1\right)^i = (q-1) \sum_{i=1}^{k-1} q^i = (q-1) \frac{q^k-q}{q-1} = q^k-k = \left(1+\frac{4}{n}\right)^k - \left(1+\frac{4}{n}\right).$$

Comment: I think you meant $q:= \frac{4}{n} +1$, right?